# Remove <intent-filter> on manifest merge

Tags: android

I need to remove specific `<intent-filter>` for debug build from `main/AndroidManifest.xml` during merging. The second one in this example:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        tools:replace="android:name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bla-bla.com" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

So when I'm trying to do `<intent-filter tools:node="remove" />` in `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` it says `bla-bla...need to specify key...`

**How to remove `<intent-filter>` for `android:host="bla-bla.com"` only or for all `android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"`???**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter tools:node="removeAll"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: This works but I'd like to remove intent-filter precisely and not to repeat all other intent-filters.